# c# DateTime Add Property without extension Method

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-2.0, extension-methods

I am writing a class library where i need to extend System.DateTime to have a property called VendorSpecificDay such that

```
DateTime txnDate = DateTime.Today;

VendorSpecificDayEnum vendorDay = txnDate.VendorSpecificDay;
```

---

```
public enum VendorSpecificDayEnum
{
    Monday, Tuesday, ShoppingDay, HolidayDay
}
```

I realize that this is a perfect candidate for a System.Core Extension method, but the class library is in .net 2.0 ( i know i am living in dark ages )

Given that Extension methods are syntactical sugar, is there anyway i can achieve this without them ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the C# 3.0 compiler in VS 2008, you can use extension methods even if your project targets .NET 2.0. Just define your own `ExtensionAttribute`:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

As long as that type exists in a referenced assembly, you can use the `this` keyword to define extension methods, and can consume them like normal.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are just static methods, that implement "instance methods", by taking a fake "this" pointer:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int ANewFakeInstanceMethod(this SomeObject instance, string someParam)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can still invoke it just like a static method - this is how the compiler compiles your code, anyhow:

```
var inst = new SomeObject();
int result1 = inst.ANewFakeInstanceMethod("str");
int result2 = Extensions.ANewFakeInstanceMethod(inst, "str");
```

If you can't get the extension method syntax, you can still use the 2nd syntax, even if you strip the `this` from your static method definition:

```
var inst = new SomeObject();
int result2 = Extensions.ANewFakeInstanceMethod(inst, "str");

public static class Extensions
{
    public static int ANewFakeInstanceMethod(SomeObject instance, string someParam)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**BUT**

The syntax and usage you are trying to implement doesn't make sense.  You're taking an existing `DateTime` object *instance* (which has its own values for date and time), and trying to implement a new property/method off that *instance* that will return some unrelated constant.

Just use a static class, and define static read-only properties on it:

```
public static class KnownDates
{
    public static DateTime StSpruffingsDay
    {
        get
        {
            return new DateTime(1, 2, 3, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't a constant (as in, you need it for the current year), you should add a method that takes a year - not try to jam it into an extension method on top of a `DateTime`, because `DateTime` embodies more than just a year.

```
public static class KnownDates
{
    public static DateTime GetTalkLikeAPirateDay(int year)
    {
        return new DateTime( // Todo: Calculate the value, based on Sept 19th
    }
}
```

If you really need to get it relative to a `DateTime`, it still makes your code more clear to pass it to the method:

```
var fiveMinutesAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
// ...
var arrrr = KnownDates.GetTalkLikeAPirateDay(fiveMinutesAgo.Year);
```

... Than it does to invoke it straight off a `DateTime` instance:

```
var fiveMinutesAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
// ...
var arrrr = fiveMinutesAgo.GetTalkLikeAPirateDay();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net 2.0 in Visual Studio 2008 (with the C# 3.0 *compiler*), you can create your own `ExtensionAttribute`, like this:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class |
                    AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

After including this attribute, you'll be able to create extension methods in .Net 2.0 projects.

---

If you're still using VS2005, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample shows an extension *property* which (currently) doesn't exist.

"All" extension methods get you is nicer syntax, you can get *exactly* the same thing with (slightly) uglier code:

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
   static IDictionary<DateTime, VendorSpecificDayEnum> m_VendorSpecificDays = new Dictionary<DateTime, VendorSpecificDayEnum>();
   public static VendorSpecificDayEnum GetVenderSpecificDay(/*this*/ DateTime dt)
   {
      return m_VendorSpecificDays[dt];
   }
}
```

You would then write

```
VendorSpecificDayEnum vendorDay = DateTimeExtensions.GetVendorSpecificDay(txnDate);
```